# When is event sales_quote_item_set_product triggered?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I'd like to know when event `sales_quote_item_set_product` is triggered, please?

Comment: Just grep the whole code for `sales_quote_item_set_product`, locate it and look what it does. Thats how you find such stuff out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is triggered in `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` class, method `setProduct($product)`. This method sets the product for quote item and dispatches the `sales_quote_item_set_product` event along with product and quote item informations.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_item_set_product', array(
      'product' => $product,
      'quote_item' => $this
));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set a product to quote. File where the event is dispatched

```
app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Item.php
```

line 399